# Android MediaPlayer OnCompletion NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, media-player, android-mediaplayer

This is my first question. It is giving NullPointerException in media.release() line. Exact output is   NullPointerException (@ProgressDetailRecyclerViewAdapter$5:onCompletion:308) {main}

```
 public void play(String fileURL) {

    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileURL);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.release(); //line 308
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: change `mediaPlayer.release();` to `mp.release();`

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer **mp**) {
                **mediaPlayer**.release(); //line 308
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
```

use the right object mp instead of mediaPlayer inside this method

Comment: Hey Uma, mp.stop() is required or not above mp.release()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release(); //line 308
                mp= null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey quick Learner, mp.stop() is required or not above mp.release()

Comment: did you call mp.stop(); ?

Answer (score 0):

The variable that gets passed to your `onCompletion` method is named `mp`, not `mediaPlayer`. It's possible your `mediaPlayer` variable has been nulled since it was initialized, causing the error. Change the code to:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.release(); //line 308
    mp = null;
}
```

Comment: Hey Jokab, mp.stop() is required or not above mp.release()

Comment: @UpendraSinghChauhan there is no `mp.stop` in your code. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: yes, that is not written in my question, but I am asking that mp.stop() is required or not before releasing the resources (mp.release). Is it a good practice to use that, that's I wanted to know. I am new to android development.

Comment: I don't think it matters.